# Parse html and javascript page

Tags: javascript, php, html, parsing

I tried parse html page with php function file_get_contents, unfortunately this function doesn't work for this url: http://www.xscores.com/hockey/usa/2010-2011/phi_flyers/team_results . I need parse all results from this page. It would be only for me, not for public. Maybe javascript could be a problem? Thanks for help.

Comment: What result are you getting from file_get_contents? Upon visiting the link you provided with a browser I couldn't find any results amongst the page that was delivered.

Comment: I getting page without result, see http://johy.g6.cz/test/index.php